# Android has default splash screen? How do I modify it?

Tags: android, layout

It seems that Android has a default splash screen. I didn't make any splash screen but every time I open my application, a splash screen appears. The title bar of my splash screen contains a string which is the name of my application. It also uses the same background as what I've set on my application.

Why does my application shows a splash screen? Is this a default on Android? I checked other applications developed by others and it doesn't have a splash screen.

How do I remove the string on the title bar of my splash screen? How can I change the background of my splash screen without affecting the background of my other activities?

Sample code of my first activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //initialize variables
    txtView1 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtView1);
    txtView2 = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
    ...
    //register broadcast receiver
    ...
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    //read bundle if a bundle exists
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I didn't make any splash screen but every time I open my application, a splash screen appears.

Android does not add a splash screen to applications.

> The title bar of my splash screen contains a string which is the name of my application. It also uses the same background as what I've set on my application.

This is one of your activities. Specifically, it is the one which has the following `<intent-filter>` in the manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

> Why does my application shows a splash screen?

Because that is what you wrote. Whatever activity you have tied to the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` is causing this effect. You need to read your manifest file, identify this activity, take a look at the activity code, and determine what it is that you wrote.

> Is this a default on Android?

No.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't wrote a code to display a splash screen on my first activity. That is why I am wondering what is causing it. Could it be what Craigy had said? That my first activity is taking too long to load causing a splash screen-like display to appear while waiting for my activity to finish loading?

Comment: @Arci: Launch the activity, wait ~5 seconds, and start tapping on the background. If you get an "Activity Not Responding" error dialog, then, yes, you are taking too long on the main application thread.

Comment: It only takes less than a second for my activity to load. The splash screen is shown only for a very short period of time. I forgot to mention that the splash screen shows even the application I'm launching is only a hello world application.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe it sounds like your activity's `onCreate` method is taking a long time to run. Make sure you don't perform long-running operations directly on the UI thread.

Database operations, network operations, and computationally intensive operations should be done in a separate thread. See [this page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for android threading options.

Comment: Thanks! Then the splash screen I am seeing is actually my first activity waiting to for its UI to load completely?

Comment: That is just my first guess... are you doing anything that might take a while in your activity's `onCreate` or `onStart`? It would be easier to provide a definitive answer if you post some code

Comment: I'm not sure if it really takes a while but basically, I'm just initializing my variables inside the onCreate() method. I added my code above.

Comment: I don't see anything suspect in the code you posted. You could put log statements at the ends of these methods to see how long they take to complete. At least it would rule out whether this is the issue or not

Comment: I don't think its because of how long does my application takes to load. I remember I tried to create a hello world application before and it also shows a splash screen. The other application I made also shows a splash screen.

Comment: What device are you seeing this behavior on?

Comment: I'm using Samsung Galaxy Y and Huawei Ideos.

Comment: Well sorry, I don't know what might be causing it. Android does not put a splash screen on apps, but if you are seeing delay like that it is not normal, at least in my experience.

Comment: Thanks, Craigy! I'm not sure also why it acts like that. Maybe I should upload a picture because I might be using the wrong term.